# Cross Compilation: How to use same libstdc++ on target as on compiling machine

Tags: cross-compiling, openwrt

I am running openwrt on a TP-Link MR3020 and cross compiling for this device on a x86 ubuntu.
I am running into problems and the remote debugging doesnt help very much.

Maybe the c++ standard libraries from the toolchain that I use to compile with are different from the ones on the target machine.
How can I check which version is installed?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can see the different options of toolchain like Binutils Version, GCC compiler Version, ...

Just execute the command below and follow the instruction

```
make menuconfig
```

enter to "Advanced configuration options (for developers)" then enter to "Toolchain Options"

and you can see the different options of toolchain like Binutils Version, GCC compiler Version, ...